# Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 Mini (E10i) stuck on boot logo after installing a custom ROM using CWM Recovery

Tags: custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, boot-loop, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I was trying to install a custom ROM on my Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 Mini (E10i) by flashing the ROM with the `.zip` file in ClockWorkMod Recovery, but after installation the device doesn't boot. It hangs on the Sony Ericsson boot logo.

What can I do to recover from this situation?

Comment: Did you unlock bootloader and flashed kernel?

Comment: Can you still boot to recovery? If so, a first step would be wiping cache and Dalvik. If that doesn't do the job, a factory-reset can be issued from the same place (which of course would delete all your apps and data, if they were still present before that).

Answer (score 1):

If you unlocked your bootloader and flashed a custom kernel, try:

1. Hold Home and Power button, phone will restart.
2. Press back button repeatedly, phone will boot into recovery.
3. Now
   wipe data,
   wipe cache,
   dalvik chache,
   dalvik battery status. In mount n system:
   format data,
   format system,
   format cache.
4. Now flash your rom zip and after successful flash, reboot the phone.

Note: Always flash the kernel which is given along with the rom

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the stock ROM. Download (stock ROM) FTF file from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2105836) and flash it using Flashtool.

Answer (score 0):

I had this too but it was because I forgot to clean dalvik cache. Go into recovery> wipe dalvik cache> install zip from sd card. Then it should work